# Parametric Geodesics of a 2-sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, geodesics

The geodesic equations of a 2-sphere are the following:

$$\ddot\theta - \sin\theta \cos\theta\dot\phi = 0$$

$$\ddot\phi + 2\cot(\theta)\dot\theta \dot\phi = 0$$

For $\theta$=$\pi$/2, $\phi(s)$=a$s$+b. In order to avoid solving the differential equations, I was trying to do an axis rotation of the equatorial solution, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Is this thought process correct? If it is how would you do it?

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.